# Print the directory with the most files in unix/linux

Tags: linux, unix

I'm new to Stack Overflow, so be patient.

I'm in a directory which contains both files and directories. I want a command to print out the name of the directory (out of a few specified directories) that has the greatest number of files in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
for d in */ ; do echo "$d" $(find $d -type f | wc -l); done | sort -n -k 2
```

Explanation:

```
for d in *
```

Loop through directories only

```
echo "$d" $(find $d -type f | wc -l)
```

Show the directory name and the count of its files (recursively)

```
sort -n -k 2
```

Sort numerically the output of the whole thing (for loop) by using the second field (the number of files)

Comment: That works beautifully, @redobot. If I wanted to print the directory with the largest number, would I just add  | tail -1 to the end?

Comment: Yes, adding a "|tail -1" you will get the last line of the output